# Traveller travelled based on data range - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, overlap

I want to return all the travellers who are currently travelling when I supply a **From** and **To** date. Meaning if I travel from **1 Jan 2022** until **10 Jan 2022** and I supply a **From** date as **5 Jan 2022** and a **To** date **15 Jan 2022** I must be retuned as I was travelling during that time period. So in my code below Mike must be returned.

```
DECLARE @DateFrom      DATE         = '2022-01-05',
        @DateTo        DATE         = '2022-01-15'

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Dates

CREATE TABLE #Dates
(
    DepartureDate  Date       NULL,
    ReturnDate     Date       NULL,
    Name           VARCHAR(8) NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Dates (DepartureDate, ReturnDate, Name)
VALUES ('2022-01-01', '2022-01-10', 'Mike' )

SELECT * 
FROM   #Dates
WHERE  DepartureDate >= @DateFrom
AND    ReturnDate    <= @DateTo
```

If you select date range between '2021-12-01' and '2021-12-05' then Mike did not travel so should not be returned. But if you select date range between '2022-01-05' and '2022-01-15' then Mike should be returned as Mike did travel in that date range even though he did not travel all the days.

Comment: Ok. What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overlapping intervals problem! Check that each interval starts before the other interval ends:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   #Dates
WHERE  DepartureDate <= @DateTo
AND    ReturnDate    >= @DateFrom
```

Comment: Aside: The description of the [`overlap`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/overlap/info) tag has a handy explanation.

Comment: I didn't know, and I was lazy to search, thanks @HABO!

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is your `WHERE` clause doesn't work for all cases to support your problem description.

This is one way you could write it to fix it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #Dates
WHERE  
    (DepartureDate >= @DateFrom AND ReturnDate <= @DateTo) -- Traveled only between provided date range
    OR (DepartureDate < @DateFrom AND ReturnDate > @DateTo) -- Traveled the entire date range, possibly longer 
    OR (DepartureDate < @DateFrom AND ReturnDate <= @DateTo AND ReturnDate >= @DateFrom) -- Started traveling before date range but finished traveling within it 
    OR (DepartureDate >= @DateFrom AND DepartureDate <= @DateTo AND ReturnDate > @DateTo) -- Started traveling within the date range but finished traveling after
```

Please see the comments on each case.

Alternatively you can write this as 4 `SELECT` statements (one for each case) with a `UNION ALL` clause too. Sometimes the SQL Server Engine produces a more efficient query plan when writing queries this way as opposed to multiple `OR` predicates:

```
-- Traveled only between provided date range
SELECT * 
FROM #Dates
WHERE  
    DepartureDate >= @DateFrom 
    AND ReturnDate <= @DateTo

UNION ALL

-- Traveled the entire date range, possibly longer
SELECT * 
FROM #Dates
WHERE 
    DepartureDate < @DateFrom 
    AND ReturnDate > @DateTo 
    
UNION ALL

-- Started traveling before date range but finished traveling within it 
SELECT * 
FROM #Dates
WHERE
    DepartureDate < @DateFrom 
    AND ReturnDate <= @DateTo
    AND ReturnDate >= @DateFrom

UNION ALL

-- Started traveling within the date range but finished traveling after
SELECT * 
FROM #Dates
WHERE
    DepartureDate >= @DateFrom 
    AND DepartureDate <= @DateTo
    AND ReturnDate > @DateTo
```

You'd have to test both ways to see which one performs better for your particular case.

---

Side note, don't use `SELECT *` because it's an [anti-pattern](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/220216/150011). Rather you should explicitly list out only the columns the query needs.

Comment: Does not work if The DateFrom and DateTo is in the past, say in 2021, then Mike is still returned when he should not be as he did not travel in 2021.

Comment: @Etienne Please elaborate with a more complete example, I don't understand. If the `DateFrom` and `DateTo` fields are in the past, 2021, with your current data example of Mike traveling in 2022, he did not travel during the timeframe of 2021 then.

Comment: If you select date range between '2021-12-01' and '2021-12-05' then Mike did not travel so should not be returned. But if you select date range between '2022-01-05' and '2022-01-15' then Mike should be returned as Mike did travel in that date range even though he did not travel all the days.

Comment: @Etienne Sorry I see what you mean. I missed one predicate clause. I've fixed it now, please see my updated query.